# Django: How to remove the list that appears from raising a ValidationError

Tags: python, django, validation, web, error-handling

I want to raise a validation error so that the red box appears in the following image, but I do not want the list to appear. It would seem that `forms.ValidationError("")` forces you to input some text so that it can appear in this error list but I already handled that in my .html with `{% if form.errors %}` (display the red box). Is there a way to stop this list from appearing?

[image: ValidationError]

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form): 
    username = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput 
               (attrs={'placeholder': 'Username or Email', 'class': 'login-field'})) 
    password = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput 
               (attrs={'placeholder': 'Password', 'class': 'login-field'})) 

    def clean(self): 
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username') 
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password') 
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password) 
    if not user or not user.is_active: 
        raise forms.ValidationError("") 
    return self.cleaned_data 

    def login(self, request): 
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username') 
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password') 
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password) 
        return user
```

Comment: Don't confuse the data and it's representation. If you want a different (e.g. no) representation of the error handle it in your view or template. Also make sure that the situation is transparent to the user. An error without message usually isn't.

Comment: Please post your template code

Comment: @Selcuk I posted it.

Comment: This is your form, not template. Please post the relevant parts of your html template.